# How to prevent pasting of non-numerical values in textbox?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs

```js
app.directive('allowPattern', [allowPatternDirective]);
function allowPatternDirective() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        compile: function (tElement, tAttrs) {
            return function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind("keypress", function (event) {
                     var keyCode = event.which || event.keyCode; 
                    if ((keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90) || (keyCode >= 97 && keyCode <= 122)) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    }
                });

            };
        }
    };
}
```

```html
<input type="text" allow-pattern="[0-9]" autofocus />
```

How to prevent pasting in textbox when the Pasted content is not applicable for that field? (It should paste for applicable conten )

Application Background: C#, AngularJS

I have a textbox in my application which should accept numbers only. Currently I am using a directive for Keypress which prevents entering the non-numeric values. But when I copy-paste the non-numeric values along with numeric values(Ex: NUMBER123), it is getting pasted. But the requirement is it should not paste at all. How can I achieve this through appropriate angular js directives/ jquery.

Comment: Post the code here

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and reform your question. Providing more details including your current code and things you already done will make helping much easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your requirement.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('allowNumbers', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
      function test(text) {
        var input = text.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
        if(input !== text) {
            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue("");
            ngModelCtrl.$render();
        }
        return input;
      }
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(test);
    }
  }; 
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
  
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Directive</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <input allow-numbers type="text" ng-model="test" autofocus>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Please run this snippet**

[Js fiddle of the directive](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/11087/)

Comment: Thank You.
But here's also one issue.

Comment: if i Paste "abc123" - it pastes "123". But as per my requirement it should not paste at all if the copied value has non numeric values. What are the changes I have to make it to do so?

Comment: Updated the answer, check now

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your head part and your text box should be like this.

```js
function onlyNos(e, t) {
  try {
    if (window.event) {
      var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
    } else if (e) {
      var charCode = e.which;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  } catch (err) {
    alert(err.Description);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="return onlyNos(event,this);" />
```

Comment: This will not prevent from pasting non numeric values!!